# How to add multiple sections under same tab magento admin panel?

Tags: magento-1.7

I am trying to add multiple section under same tab in magento admin panel. I added this in system.xml file. It works fine for one section but when i add another it display the section but after click it throw `404 not fount error`.

I am using the below code :

```
<tabs>
    <mss translate="label" module="sqlite">
        <label>Mss Extensions</label>
        <sort_order>100</sort_order>
    </mss>
</tabs>
<sections>
        <mss translate="label" module="sqlite">
            <label>Auto Indexing</label>
            <tab>mss</tab>
            <sort_order>1000</sort_order>
            <show_in_default>1</show_in_default>
            <show_in_website>1</show_in_website>
            <show_in_store>1</show_in_store>


        <groups>
            <mss_group translate="label" module="sqlite">
                <label>Indexing Options</label>
                <frontend_type>text</frontend_type>
                <sort_order>10</sort_order>
                <show_in_default>1</show_in_default>
                <show_in_website>1</show_in_website>
                <show_in_store>1</show_in_store>

                <fields>
                    <mss_input translate="label">
                        <label>Auto Products</label>
                        <frontend_type>select</frontend_type>
                        <sort_order>90</sort_order>
                        <show_in_default>1</show_in_default>
                        <show_in_website>1</show_in_website>
                        <show_in_store>1</show_in_store>
                        <source_model>adminhtml/system_config_source_yesno</source_model>
                    </mss_input>

                </fields>
            </mss_group>
        </groups>
    </mss>
</sections>
<sections

 <sqlite translate="label" module="sqlite">
            <label>Auto Indexing</label>
            <tab>mss</tab>
            <sort_order>100</sort_order>
            <show_in_default>1</show_in_default>
            <show_in_website>1</show_in_website>
            <show_in_store>1</show_in_store>

        <groups>
            <sqlite_group translate="label" module="sqlite">
                <label>Sqlite Process</label>
                <frontend_type>text</frontend_type>
                <sort_order>1000</sort_order>
                <show_in_default>1</show_in_default>
                <show_in_website>1</show_in_website>
                <show_in_store>1</show_in_store>

                <fields>
                    <sqlite_input translate="label">
                        <label>Sqlite Product</label>
                        <frontend_type>select</frontend_type>
                        <sort_order>90</sort_order>
                        <show_in_default>1</show_in_default>
                        <show_in_website>1</show_in_website>
                        <show_in_store>1</show_in_store>
                        <source_model>adminhtml/system_config_source_yesno</source_model>
                    </sqlite_input>

                </fields>
            </sqlite_group>
        </groups>
    </sqlite>
</sections>
```

**1 )** This is my mss section this works fine

[image]

**2)** This is section which i am trying to with name sqlite (when i click on this section this throws 404 error)

[image]

Please help me how to add new section in tab or where i am doing wrong.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to have this in the `adminhtml.xml` file of your module:

```
<acl>
    <resources>
        <admin>
            <children>
                <system>
                    <children>
                        <config>
                            <children>
                                <mss translate="title">
                                    <title>Auto Indexing Mss</title>
                                </mss>
                                <sqlite translate="title">
                                    <title>Auto Indexing Sqlite </title>
                                </sqlite>
                            </children>
                        </config>
                    </children>
                </system>
            </children>
        </admin>
    </resources>
</acl>
```

After adding this, clear the cache and log out and relogin in the backend.

Comment: @DeepakMankotia. If this solved your problem, mark the answer as accepted. Let's keep a clean website.